# How to find asymptotic behavior of this function?

Tags: analysis, functions

I've read in a book that this function:
$$b(r) = \sqrt{\frac{r^3}{r - 2M}}$$
behaves approximately as
$$ b(r) \approx r + M $$
for $r \gg M$.

I checked it numerically, by plotting a graph of this function, and found that it is true. How to show this mathematically?

Comment: $b(r)=r(1-2M/r)^{-1/2}$ and the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R >0.$

$b(R)=R(1-2M/R)^{-1/2}.$

Binomial expansion for rational exponent $\alpha$:

$(1+x)^{\alpha}=$

$ 1+\alpha x+(\alpha (\alpha-1)/2!)x^2+ O(x^3)$

converges for $|x|<1.$

Hence for large  $R$:

$b(R)=R(1+M/R +O((M/R)^2))$
https://brilliant.org/wiki/fractional-binomial-theorem/

Answer (score 4):

This is just a Taylor expansion
$$b(r) = \sqrt{\frac{r^3}{r - 2M}}=r \sqrt{\frac{r}{r - 2M}}$$
Use long division or Taylor series
$$\frac{r}{r - 2M}=1+\frac{2 M}{r}+\frac{4 M^2}{r^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^3}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{r}{r - 2M}}=1+\frac{M}{r}+\frac{3 M^2}{2 r^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^3}\right)$$
$$b(r)=r+M+\frac{3 M^2}{2 r}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)=r+M+O\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{r^3}{r - 2M}}}{r+M}=\sqrt{\frac{r^3}{(r-2M)(r+M)^2}}=$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{r^3}{r^3\left(1-\frac{2M}r\right)\left(1+\frac Mr\right)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{2M}r\right)\left(1+\frac Mr\right)^2}}\to 1$$ as $r\to\infty$.

Comment: While this is true, it works for $r+K$ for any constant $K$, so I don't think it fundamentally addresses OP's question.